# Match strings not starting with dot or : character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the text below and I want to match the variable and the function types only. So on the first line I want to match only the first "float", on the second line I want to match the first and the third "float" and then same for the "int".

Of course this is dynamic, basically I want to match with a regex strings that do not start with a dot or a : symbol. I tried with negative lookahead but couldn't make it work

```
float JsValue.float
float JsValue:float(float testFloat)
int JsValue.int
int JsValue:int(int testInt)
```

The regex below captures everything which is not what I want.

```
\b(int|bool|float)\b
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of lookbehind you can use negated character class:

```
/(?:^|[^:.])\b(int|bool|float)\b/mg
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tF6zP7/1)

Comment: How would you do the same thing with lookbehind? I am using a library that mitigates JavaScript’s lack of lookbehind.

Comment: Using lookbehind it will be: `(?<![:.])\b(int|bool|float)\b`

Comment: The first regex without lookbehind it works but it also captures the "(" character before the variable type. I am using PrismJS for coloring and trying to make it work, the lookbehind variant looks to be handled differently. [link](http://prismjs.com/extending.html)

Comment: To avoid capturing `(` before you need full lookbehind support. Without lookbehind you can use captured group #1 which is without `(`

Comment: I understand that, sadly Prism does not give that flexibility (or at least I haven't found any documentation indicating that).

Comment: Since this question was tagged as JS that's why my answer is for pure JS. You can open a new question for prism library if you want.